# Php sign-up error

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include './includes/connect_db.php' // connecting to mysql server  ?>   
<?php include './includes/select_db.php' //  selecting database ?>
<?php
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password=$_POST["pass"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];             
$sql="insert into table 'users' values ('$username','$password','$email')";
if(mysql_query($sql,$connect))
{
    echo "query executed";
}
else
{
    echo "query did not run ".mysql_error();
} ?>

<?php include './includes/close_db.php' ; //closing connection ?>
```

the table consists of 4 fields, (id,username,password,email).
"id" is the primary key and auto incremented.
everything is working fine except the query and php is not diplaying what error is in query despite display_error is ON is .ini file.

Comment: what is $connect in your if condition?

Comment: it is the variable which creates the connection

Comment: How it is creating connection? echo $connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couple of problems there.. Firstly, you dont need to start and close the php interpreter so many times (using php open and close tags for your includes).. just open it once.

You haven't defined connect - and I'd recommend keeping it outside of your if statement. From what I can see there, it won't connect where it is anyway.. but I can't see how you've defined it.

Set up your db connection first, and then change your $sql to read;

```
$sql="INSERT INTO 'users' 
values ('{$username}','{$password}','{$email}')";
```

That should then work fine for you.

Best of luck with it!

- Eoghan

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')";
$link = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Change `(username, password, email)` into your own column values.

Answer (score 0):

You could echo out the $sql line and then copy and paste it into PHPmyadmin's SQL tab. This will tell you if your SQL is correct. And also put the field names in your query.

Comment: It looks like comment or suggestion not answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below sql command

```
$sql="insert into users values ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mysql_query($sql,$connect) or die mysql_error()
```

to get the actual error

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES('$username','$password','$email')";
```

if your error persists copy the following code:

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "pass";
  $dbname = "myDB";

  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
  $myusername1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name1']);
  $mylastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lastname']);
  $myemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
  #the if statement is just an example of when you to control the flow of your code
  if($myusername == $myusername1){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (name, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('$myusername', '$mylastname', '$myemail')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
  }else{
    echo "Error: Check your username!!!";
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```